# Is there a way to get the size of a type within a generic function without reflection?

Tags: go, generics

In the case of a generic function that does byte serialization for a generic types, is there a way to proceed--other than reflection--if the different supported types have different sizes? For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)   

type KeyType interface {
    uint16 | uint32 | uint64
}   

type Item[KT KeyType] struct {
    Key  KT  
    Data []byte
}   

// set of generic types that hold collections of Item[T]
// sets of methods that operate on those generic types

func MarshalBinary[KT KeyType](i *Item[KT]) ([]byte, error) {
    // How do I compute the size of the item and marshal it?
    // It's 2 bytes for uint16, 4 for uint32, 8 for uint64,
    // how do I distinguish here?
}   

func main() {
    i := new(Item[uint32])
    i.Key = 42
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Is there a way to access the size of the type within the serialization function without reflection?

I know I can proceed with reflection like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type KeyType interface {
    uint16 | uint32 | uint64
}

type Item[KT KeyType] struct {
    Key  KT
    Data []byte
}

// set of generic types that hold collections of Item[T]
// sets of methods that operate on those generic types

func MarshalBinary[KT KeyType](i *Item[KT]) ([]byte, error) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(i)
    var size int
    if strings.Contains(t.String(), `uint32`) {
        size = 4
    }
    fmt.Println(size)
    // rest of function here
    return nil, nil
}

func main() {
    i := new(Item[uint32])
    i.Key = 42
    MarshalBinary(i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Is there a better way? My main concern with using reflection here is the potential performance cost.

Comment: I'm not sure about performance changes, but you can use `unsafe.Sizeof()`. Also, the common pattern I see in Go code for these problem is to implement for the type most of the time function will receive and check the error

Answer (score -1):

First off, I think your sample code may be incorrect, because you're using `reflect.TypeOf(i)`, but `i` is of type `Item[KT]`, and since `Item` includes both a `KT` and a `[]byte`, it will be the size of `KY` **plus** the size of a pointer (the pointer to the byte slice). So, it will be 4 + pointer size if `KT` is a `uint32`, but you're setting it to 4.

So the question is, are you trying to get the size of `i` (`Item[KT]`), or the size of an instance of `KT`?

I assume it's the size of `KT` that you're actually looking for, since you're assigning a size of 4 if it's a `uint32`. You can do this without `reflect` by casting the value you want the size of as an `interface{}`, then using a standard type switch, as follows:

```golang
func MarshalBinary[KT KeyType](i *Item[KT]) ([]byte, error) {
    var size int
    switch (interface{})(i.Key).(type) {
    case uint16:
        size = 2
    case uint32:
        size = 4
    case uint64:
        size = 8
    default:
        panic("Unexpected type")
    }
    ...
}
```

This is a bit problematic if you ever want to expand the different possible types that `KeyType` could be, though.